Where are mouse and kb battery levels in 24.10
I'm using Ubuntu 24.10 on a System76 Ratel Pro with Bluetooth mouse and keyboard. It used to be (I think as recently as 24.04) that if I looked at Settings->Power, I could see graphical displays for the battery levels of these devices. But I don't see this in 24.10. Where should I look in 24.10 to see the battery levels for my mouse and keyboard?
Keyboard: Logitech K480.
Mouse: Logitech M535.

After this command:
    sudo apt reinstall --purge bluez gnome-bluetooth

the "Connected Devices" section under Settings->Power has returned.
This has the battery levels for my kb and mouse.

Unfortunately, this fix seems to be temporary. The next day, the "Connected Devices" section was again missing from Settings->Power. Repeating the above command brings it back. Clearly, a more permanent solution is needed.
